# JwPlayer seemingly timing-out

Tags: php, video-streaming, jwplayer, playback, intermittent

I'm using JwPlayer as my default player for my new CMS site.  When video content was low (remote/external links to videos only) JwPlayer was working fine on my website.

Now I have 1000s of video links (remote) and JwPlayer seems to be timing out with frequency just as I immediately click the play button as soon as screen loads-up.  I will get " File Not Found" messages when trying to play a video right-away, BUT if I refresh/reload the web-page (using Google Chrome) anywhere between 5-6 times, it'll push the play through and work.

At times, not always, I also get intermittent video play, but I imagine that has to do with my internet connection at times.  If not, or if there's a value to adjust for better play, please let me know.

Comment: Please give us a link to your site.

Comment: Indeed, a link is needed to debug this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I intentionally left off the link since the site an adult content site, but here it is fellas: spankwank dot com - Thank you in advance for your help! - BTW, I noticed that the videos are REALLY intermittent when viewed in full screen.

Comment: I noticed that when you find a video that doesn't load up, i.e. "Error Loading Media: File cannot be played" and you refresh the page and QUICKLY click the Play Button on the video, as soon as the graphic populates, it pushes the play function through.  To me, this means that there's an extremely narrow "time-out" value in the very beginning of the page w/video clip loading-up.

Comment: No problems here, so I think you just have a lousy connection. But you're using JW Player 6, but pointing to the JW 5 version of the Flash player. Potential problems, there.

Comment: How about a safe for work page?

Comment: @Ethan: JW Player really has cornered the market on sleazy porn! It's either that, or Jeebus.

Comment: We see many different use cases for the player, that's for sure...

Comment: Fellas, I appreciate you taking a moment to review my issue, especially with the nature of the material. =)  Please take a moment to rapidly toggle through a variety of videos, to see if you can replicate the video-load-failure.  It occurs spordically. Thank you in advance. =)

Comment: You're going to have to put up a non-crap-porno test site before anyone can help you. Sorry.